# Почему не срабатывает PJAX форма?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

**Первый раз** решил применить **pjax** на сайте, но наткнулся на такую **ошибку в консоле**:

```
Uncaught $.fn.pjax or $.pjax.click requires an anchor element
jquery.pjax.min.js:1
```

**вот мой PJAX:**

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]', function(event) {
    $.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax-container')
})
```

**а это фрагмент кода формы:**

```
<form id="j-f-form" data-pjax action="экшен" method="get" class="form-inline rel">
    инпуты субмиты итд
</form>
```

в чем косяк ? помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

У Вас id формы - j-f-form, а в $.pjax.submit Вы указываете #pjax-container

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]', function(event) {
  $.pjax.submit(event, '#j-f-form')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.pjax/2.0.1/jquery.pjax.js"></script>

<form id="j-f-form" data-pjax action="/search" method="get" class="form-inline rel">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search query">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```